# Function to check if a date is a Christmas day or New Years day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a function in SQL Server to validate if given date is a Christmas day or new year's day. Please kindly advise if following code is OK:

```
Declare @paramDate date
....
IF Month(@paramDate) = 12 and DAY(@paramDate) = 25
     or Month(@paramDate) = 1 and DAY(@paramDate) = 1
BEGIN
   ....
```

Above is the simplest way I can think of regardless or timezone and date format

Comment: By "simple" do you mean fewest number of characters/lines, most intuitive, something else?

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes that's correct ^^, it's a nice way to wrap it up

Comment: @AaronBertrand, sorry I mean "fewest number of characters/lines"

Comment: @Dreamer: simple generally means, the easiest to understand, rather than the tersest.

Comment: Ok, because trying to minimize the number of characters as a goal tends to have the opposite effect - it tends to makes things more cryptic and unintuitive. The term you probably mean is _terse_, not _simple_.

Comment: I see, then most of the time simplest should more lean to `intuitive`. Cool I even complete an English class in this post, guess it's a big win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a table-valued function like this, rather than what I suspect is a scalar function based on the syntax in your question. Your checks are fine, I don't think they can be any simpler and still be intuitive, but another way to test for specific dates is to compare to `DATEFROMPARTS()`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsSpecificHoliday
(
  @d date
)
RETURNS table WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
      SELECT IsSpecificHoliday = CASE @d
        WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), 12, 25) THEN 1
        WHEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), 1,  1) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END
  );
```

Sample usage:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Dates(TheDate date);

INSERT dbo.Dates(TheDate) VALUES
  ('19701214'),('19991225'),('20400101');

SELECT d.TheDate, f.IsSpecificHoliday
  FROM dbo.Dates AS d 
  CROSS APPLY dbo.IsSpecificHoliday(d.TheDate) AS f;
```

Results:

| TheDate | IsSpecificHoliday |
| --- | --- |
| 1970-12-14 | 0 |
| 1999-12-25 | 1 |
| 2040-01-01 | 1 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=484320ce2ddd95113abc40f7660af716)

You could also always consider a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) (for this and so many other purposes) and have a calculated or pre-populated column there like `IsSpecificHoliday` and simply join to that on the date column.

Comment: A calendar table would be a good solution

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand thanks ah good to know the DATEFROMPARTS function so I guess my code should change to `IF @paramDate =DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@paramDate), 12, 25) or @paramDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@paramDate), 12, 25)`

Comment: is calendar table making better performance? kind of overkill to validate 2 simple holidays

Comment: Sure, you can use `IF` instead of `CASE`. My point was more about making sure you are using an efficient inline table-valued function, which can be incorporated into the overall execution plan, vs. a scalar-valued function which (usually) can't (and ends up getting executed _for every agonizing row_).

Comment: If this is the only thing you ever want to do with dates, then no, a calendar table is overkill. But they're tiny and like I said serve so many other purposes. See [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/), [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6848/create-a-calendar-table-in-sql-identify-date-gaps-islands/), and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6894/create-a-calendar-table-in-sql-server-to-optimize-scheduling-problems/) for some examples.

Comment: got it, thanks. So calendar table does provide better performance.

Comment: yes you are right, if `holiday` is significant in the logic and appear in multiple places then calendar table make sense.

Comment: @Dreamer Right, it's definitely more about simplification of logic and flexibility than performance. If you have 10 different places where you have this `IF` or `CASE` expression, and you need to add July 4th or Easter or Super Mario Day or whatever, you just update the table instead of those 10 different places. Also good luck with Easter btw.

Comment: If you want a Calendar table (Date dimension) with computed holidays in several countries (including Easter), I have this here: https://github.com/Mitch-Wheat/DateAndTimeDimension

Answer (score 0):

You can use the implicit conversion in concert with the `right()` function

**Example**

```
Declare @date date = '2021-12-25'

Select case when right(@date,5) in ('12-25','01-01') then 1 else 0 end
```

With an explicit conversion

```
Declare @date date = '2021-12-25'

Select case when convert(varchar(5),@date,101)  in ('12/25','01/01') then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: This method is inferior to posters method.

Comment: @MitchWheat I disagree

Comment: I don't think it's _bad_, per se, but you're definitely taking advantage of the kind of undocumented implicit conversion that continues to bite people who have code like `@StartDate + 1` when `@StartDate` parameter (or variable or column) changes from `datetime` to `date`, `datetime2`, or `datetimeoffset`. I would much rather perform an explicit conversion to a specific style unless it's code golf.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Noted, but paramDate clearly has a datatype of date.

Comment: I know the parameter's datatype, I don't know that the undocumented implicit conversion behavior will always work. (Behavior has changed in elements other than manual data type changes, e.g. ORDER BY in a view.) It really doesn't hurt anything to perform an _explicit_ conversion instead of relying on an implicit one, again, unless the purpose is a race to the fewest number of characters. One more time: I'm not saying it's _bad_. It can just be a little less risky at a very small incremental cost.

Comment: (Never mind that the maintainer of whatever function gets created could change the input parameter's type at any time, for any reason, without even looking at the code, understanding the assumptions that were made, or caring that it could change the behavior. It's the same reason I don't like relying on `date` as the only exception where I can use `yyyy-mm-dd` in any language or still get a seek even when I convert a column. These exceptions are very brittle.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'll agree an explicit conversion would be safer.  This was not a "race to the fewest characters".  If that was the case I would have opted for an IIF()  :)   Furthermore, additional dates like July 4th would be a small matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, looks to me a pretty simple solution. As an Oracle guy I am not familiar with date format in Date type in SQL server, so as July 4th as example, is it always stay as `2021-07-04` in the date type column or any chance it can change to `04-07-2021` in certain locale

Comment: @Dreamer date values in a column aren't stored in any format. Where you get in trouble with locales is when SQL Server needs to interpret a string literal representing a datetime, e.g. doing things like `DECLARE @d datetime = '2021-07-04 03:00:00.000';` and wondering why you get a report for July 4th but your users in Europe get a report for April 7th. https://sqlblog.org/dates

Comment: @Dreamer the datatype DATE does not have a format.  If you want to be double safe for different locales use the explicit conversion   For example  case when convert(varchar(5),@date,101)  in ('12/25','01/01') then 1 else 0 end   101 will go MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @Dreamer  See updated answer

Comment: thanks John and Aaron, this could be most fruitful question I have ever asked :) learned quite a lot of extra.